# How to redirect to Home page?

Tags: asp.net-core, razor-pages, blazor

ConfirmEmail page contains:

```
public async Task<IActionResult> OnGetAsync(string userId, string code)
{
    if (userId == null || code == null)
    {
        return RedirectToPage("/Index"); // <----------error
    }

    var user = await _userManager.FindByIdAsync(userId);
    if (user == null)
    {
        return NotFound($"Unable to load user with ID '{userId}'.");
    }

    code = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(WebEncoders.Base64UrlDecode(code));
    var result = await _userManager.ConfirmEmailAsync(user, code);
    StatusMessage = result.Succeeded ? "Thank you for confirming your email." : "Error confirming your email.";

    return Page();
}
```

But when I test it for null parameters it tries to redirect to page
 return RedirectToPage("/Index");

it generates the exception:

> An unhandled exception occurred while processing the request.
>   InvalidOperationException: No page named '/Index' matches the supplied
>   values

How to redirect to the home page?

Comment: `RedirectToPage("/Index")` will effectively look for `Pages/Index.cshtml` – Does such a page exist?

Comment: The page ConfirmEmailcshtml  is on ...\Areas\Identity\Pages\Account, the Index.razor is on ...\Pages

Comment: `RedirectToPage()` will make a HTTP redirect to a *Razor page*, not a Blazor page. The `Index.razor` is a Blazor component and likely your start page. In that case, you want to redirect to just the root so that the Blazor application restarts and picks up its own client-side routing.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63711424/how-to-use-aspmenuitem-navigateurl-property-to-call-blazorserver-app-in-the-sam
 can you answer this question?  @ZedZip

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It works this way if pages located in different folders

```
return Redirect("~/");
```

Answer (score 2):

`RedirectToPage()` returns an `IActionResult` that makes a HTTP redirect to the route that you specified by giving the path of the *Razor page*. Razor pages are the `.cshtml` files inside the `Pages` folder.

If you are using Blazor, then you are likely using the client-side router it comes with. In that case, there is only a single Razor page `_Host.cshtml` which will act as the primary entry point to your Blazor application.

So what you *could* do is make a redirect to `/_Host` although I would not recommend that. Instead, just making a redirect to the application root, *without* asking the server-side endpoint router what the route is, is probably the best idea:

```
return LocalRedirect("/");
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63711424/how-to-use-aspmenuitem-navigateurl-property-to-call-blazorserver-app-in-the-sam
 can you answer this question?

Answer (score 1):

In **Blazor** you should use `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.NavigationManager`.

```
@inject NavigationManager NavigationManager

if (userId == null || code == null)
    {
        NavigationManager.NavigateTo("/Index"); // <----------error
    }
```

Comment: It does not return any results but this method should return

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63711424/how-to-use-aspmenuitem-navigateurl-property-to-call-blazorserver-app-in-the-sam
 can you answer this question?